# How Do I Retain Date & Time Formats In A Google Sheet Via Google Apps Script To An Emailed HTML Table

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, html-table

I am using the following code...

```
 function getEmailHtml(appearanceData){
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template.html");
  htmlTemplate.appearance = appearanceData;
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  return htmlBody;}

function sendEmail() {
  var appearanceData = getData();
  var body = getEmailText(appearanceData);
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml(appearanceData);

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "XXX@XXX.XXX",
    subject: "Appearances update",
    body: body,
    htmlBody: htmlBody
      });
}

  function getEmailText(appearanceData) {
  var text = "";
  appearanceData.forEach(function(appearance) {
  text = text + appearance.client + "\n" + appearance.court + "\n" + appearance.date + "\n" + appearance.time + "\n" + appearance.charges + "\n" + appearance.notes +"\n" + appearance.phone +"\n-----------------------\n\n";
  });
  return text;
}

/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function getData() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("B2:H45").getValues();
  values.shift(); //remove headers
  var appearances = [];
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    var appearance = {};
    appearance.client = value[0];
    appearance.court = value[1];
    appearance.date = value[2];
    appearance.time = value[3];
    appearance.charges = value[4];
    appearance.notes = value[5];
    appearance.phone = value[6];
    appearances.push(appearance);

     
  
})
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(appearances));
  return appearances;
```

...to extract a range of data from a spreadsheet and parse it into an HTML table, which is then sent in an email.

The code works, the table populates properly, and the email sends, but the date & time formatting from the sheet is lost in the table.

Where the sheet displays, e.g.; 7/22/2022, and e.g.; 9:00:00 AM, the execution log shows the data as:
"date":"2022-07-22T05:00:00.000Z","time":"1899-12-30T19:36:36.000Z;

and the relevant columns in the HTML table in the email output as:

Date: Fri Jul 22 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), Time: Sat Dec 30 1899 10:06:36 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), as illustrated:

[image: sample of section of table outputted to email]

I am certain this can be remedied by some operation on the relevant var appearance values, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any/all help with this!

Comment: Use[Range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())

Comment: Thanks again. Any idea how/where I would implement something like get last row so if the sheet (which auto populates from another source) changes in size I won't have a slew of blank rows at the bottom of the table?